# How to show() a <div> based on label specified in url using javascript

Tags: javascript

My html for a tabbed menu and its content:

```
<div class="tab-menu"> <!-- menu -->
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab1">link to tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">link to tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">link to tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="tab-wrapper"> <!-- content -->
<!-- BEGIN FIRST TAB -->
    <div id="tab1" class="tab">first tab content</div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab">second tab content</div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab">third tab content</div>
</div>
```

... and the script to make the menu work is

```
    // Displays the first tab when 
$(".tabs").each(function(){
    $(this).find(".tab").hide();
    $(this).find(".tab-menu li:first a").addClass("active").show();
    $(this).find(".tab:first").show();
});

$(".tabs").each(function(){

    $(this).find(".tab-menu a").click(function() {

        $(this).parent().parent().find("a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find(".tab").hide();
        var activeTab = $(this).attr("href");
        $(activeTab).fadeIn();
        return false;

    });

});
```

The menu works when user clicks a tab. This means the menu opens up with the first `<div>` visible by default and when the user clicks another tab, that corresponding `<div>` appears just as expected. However, when I type in the url `mysite/path#tab2`, it still opens up with tab1 open. What do I need to do to make it open with tab2? Specifically, how do I access the url and extract the label? I want to do this in javascript

EDIT: It seems `document.location.href` provides the full url. How do I parse and extract the label from this url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the page is loaded, check the `location.hash` property and behave consequently:

```
$(function() {
    $(".tab").hide();
    $(".tab-menu a").removeClass("active");

    $(location.hash).show();
    $(".tab-menu a[href='" + location.hash + "']").addClass("active");
});
```

Better than that, don't register any `click` listener at all, and just use the `hashchange` event:

```
$(window).hashchange(function() {
    $(".tab").hide();
    $(".tab-menu a").removeClass("active");

    $(location.hash).show();
    $(".tab-menu a[href='" + location.hash + "']").addClass("active");
});
```